# How to group an array based on a key and create a dynamic object with grouped array as values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got multiple `items`, some of them with the same `title`. I want to create an multidimensional array with the `title` as the first key and a unique number as the second key. So it's possible to categorize the `items` by `title`.

Example:

```
itemArray['title1'][0] = item1

itemArray['title1'][1] = item2

itemArray['title2'][0] = item3
```

My example is working with this code, but in my opinion it's to complicated and I hope there is an other way with JavaScript.

```js
let itemArray = {}
items.forEach(item => {
    let title = item['title']

    if (itemArray[title] == null) {
      itemArray[title] = {}
    }
    let index = Object.keys(itemArray[title]).length
    itemArray[title][index] = item
  },
)
```

The Input:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    uid: 1,
    title: 'booktitle',
    description: 'description' },
  RowDataPacket {
    uid: 2,
    title: 'booktitle',
    description: 'description 2' },
  RowDataPacket {
    uid: 1,
    title: 'booktitle 2',
    description: 'description' } ]
```

Expected output (Since it's the result of a sql query the item is a RowDataPacket):

```
{ 'booktitle':
    { '0':
      RowDataPacket {
        uid: 1,
        title: 'booktitle',
        description: 'description'  } },
    { '1':
      RowDataPacket {
        uid: 2,
        title: 'booktitle',
        description: 'description 2'  } },
  'booktitle 2':
    { '0':
      RowDataPacket {
        uid: 1,
        title: 'booktitle 2',
        description: 'description'  } }
}
```

It's easy with PHP, there it's working like this:

```
$itemArray = array();
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    $itemArray[$item['title']][] = $item;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your input and expected output :)

Comment: I've added the expected result and the input data.

Comment: @Emma Thanks, but how to use .name when the name is also just the value of an other variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the array by taking a default array and push the item.

```js
var items = [{ title: 'title1' }, { title: 'title1' }, { title: 'title2' }],
    result = items.reduce((r, item) => {
        (r[item.title] = r[item.title] || []).push(item);
        return r;
    }, {});
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks :) It's working with this solution and seems to be the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the correct idea. The `itemArray` you created is not a multidimensional array. It's an object with each `title` as key and an array of `items` which share the same `title` as their value. You could probably simplify your `forEach` like this:

```js
var items = [{
  uid: 1,
  title: 'booktitle',
  description: 'description'
}, {
  uid: 2,
  title: 'booktitle',
  description: 'description 2'
}, {
  uid: 1,
  title: 'booktitle 2',
  description: 'description'
}]

let itemArray = {}
items.forEach(item => {
  itemArray[item.title] = itemArray[item.title] || [];
  itemArray[item.title].push(item)
})

console.log(itemArray)
```

Checck if `itemArray` already has the `title` as a key. If yes, use it. Else, point it to an empty array `[]`. Then just [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the current `item` to that property.

With [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can even simplify it to:

```js
var items=[{uid:1,title:'booktitle',description:'description'},{uid:2,title:'booktitle',description:'description 2'},{uid:1,title:'booktitle 2',description:'description'}]

let itemArray = items.reduce((acc,i) => 
  ((acc[i.title] = acc[i.title] || []).push(i), acc)
,{})

console.log(itemArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Expected output
>
> `{ 'booktitle':
>           { '0':
>             RowDataPacket {
>               uid: 1,
>               title: 'booktitle',
>               description: 'description'  } },
>           { '1':
>             RowDataPacket {
>               uid: 2,
>               title: 'booktitle',
>               description: 'description 2'  } },
>         'booktitle 2':
>           { '0':
>             RowDataPacket {
>               uid: 1,
>               title: 'booktitle 2',
>               description: 'description'  } }
>       }`

That's a bad practice. Don't use enumerated properties on Objects. You see how cumbersome they are. Unlike PHP, JS has no associative Arrays; so using Objects for that is the right equivalent. But for indexed Arrays you should use Arrays in JS, not Objects.

```js
var data = [{
    uid: 1,
    title: 'booktitle',
    description: 'description'
  },
  {
    uid: 2,
    title: 'booktitle',
    description: 'description 2'
  },
  {
    uid: 1,
    title: 'booktitle 2',
    description: 'description'
  }
];

const booksByTitle = {};
for (const item of data) {
  const {
    title
  } = item;
  if (!(title in booksByTitle)) booksByTitle[title] = [];
  booksByTitle[title].push(item);
}
console.log(booksByTitle);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

but there are also plenty of frameworks in JS that offer some `groupBy` method, something like this quick implementation:

```js
var data = [{
    uid: 1,
    title: 'booktitle',
    description: 'description'
  },
  {
    uid: 2,
    title: 'booktitle',
    description: 'description 2'
  },
  {
    uid: 1,
    title: 'booktitle 2',
    description: 'description'
  }
];

function groupBy(iterable, keyOrFn) {
  const fn = typeof keyOrFn === "function" ?
    keyOrFn :
    (item) => item == null ? undefined : item[keyOrFn];

  var result = Object.create(null);
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const key = fn(item);
    if (key in result) {
      result[key].push(item);
    } else {
      result[key] = [item];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const booksByTitle = groupBy(data, "title");

console.log(booksByTitle);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```